# OneSignal - Display specific message to members who have already subscribed

Tags: onesignal

I'm using Onesignal with wordpress, where members can subscribe to notifications by clicking on a link.How can I change this link to display a specific message for already registered users?

Here is what I tried .This code displays the subscription link for people who have not subscribed yet. And displays nothing for people already subscribed. My "echo" funnction does not seem to work

Can someone help?

```
<body>
<a href="#" id="subscribe-link" style="display: none;"></i><b>  Subscribe to
notifications </b></a>
<script>
    function subscribe() {
        OneSignal.push(["registerForPushNotifications"]);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];
    /* This example assumes you've already initialized OneSignal */
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        // If we're on an unsupported browser, do nothing
        if (!OneSignal.isPushNotificationsSupported()) {
            return;
        }
        OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled) {
            if (isEnabled) { echo "You have already subscribed to notifications";

            } else {
                document.getElementById("subscribe-link").addEventListener('click', subscribe);
                document.getElementById("subscribe-link").style.display = '';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Wordpress plugin (did not disable it), then you don't need to call registerForPushNotifications.

The plugin should set the OneSignal variable for you so you can simply use the isPushNotificationsEnabled method on the page you want to check.

Try:

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled().then(function(isEnabled) {
    if (isEnabled)
      console.log("Push notifications are enabled!");
    else
      console.log("Push notifications are not enabled yet.");      
  });
});
```